# SQL DISTINCT is not removing duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, distinct

I have used below query to remove duplicates.But still it shows duplicates.Can you tell me why?

```
select DISTINCT a.Company 
from [Legacy].[dbo].[Attorney] as a
```

[image]

**Update :** Below one is also not working.Can you tell me why ?

```
select DISTINCT ltrim(rtrim(a.Company)) from [Legacy].[dbo].[Attorney] as a
```

**Update 2 :** Now,it's showing 3.I don't know why ?

```
select  DISTINCT ltrim(rtrim(a.Company)),convert(varbinary(100), a.Company) from [Legacy].[dbo].[Attorney] as a
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe there are some hidden characters or spaces, try trimming them.

Comment: Almost certainly whitespace or nasty unicode. Try looking whether there are trailing spaces; next : look at the individual code-points; could be non-printable characters, tab vs space, unicode "reverse" characters, joiners, etc

Comment: Because they aren't duplicates. If they were, DISTINCT would eliminate them. You may have trailing whitepsace, invisible characters, newlines etc. I bet that if you use `LEN(a.Company)` you'll find that the two rows have different length

Comment: @MarcGravell I have done this.Still it shows  :( `select  DISTINCT ltrim(rtrim(a.Company)) from [Legacy].[dbo].[Attorney] as a  `

Comment: Really, you should normalize out the company to a separate table to prevent issues like this.

Comment: @Sampath great, so you've ruled out whitespace at the start and the end; next, look at the individual code points; as a cheat: you could compare `CHECKSUM(a.Company)`. If that is different, **there is definitely stuff you aren't seeing**

Comment: `ltrim(rtrim(a.Company))` has no effect on space around 'C'. Or It's invisible character not treated as blank by ltrim/rtrim.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes,you're right.It's having 2 lengths. How can I remove that ? One is `15` and other is `17`

Comment: @Sampath again: look at the codepoints; try `select convert(varbinary(100), a.Company)` - find what is different

Comment: @MarcGravell Length is different. How can I remove it ? I need only one record.

Comment: @Sampath by (and I realise I'm repeating myself  here) **looking at the code-points**. If you can just paste what select `convert(varbinary(100), a.Company)` reports for your 2 examples, we can very quickly tell you what the data is and how to remove it

Comment: @MarcGravell Now,it's showing 3.I don't know why ? Please see the Update 2.

Comment: The third one has some return/newline at the end. That's why

Comment: @Sampath awesome! you have two different things here; the 2000 2000 is "space space"; the 0D00 0A00 a newline (cr/lf) pair; so... get rid of trailing whitespace and cr/lf - ideally also change your input code so you never store that; btw - users can often insert cr/lf by doing shift+enter

Comment: @MarcGravell Can you put your suggestion as an answer.It's not clear for me.Thanks.

Comment: @MarcGravell The use case here is,I'm retrieving data from the Access app.Then store them on the SQL Db.For that I need to retrieve corrected data.

Comment: @Sampath you're getting back what you put in; if you want to get back data without trailing garbage: cleanse it before you store it; or cleanse it *after* you've *fetched* it

Comment: @MarcGravell Ok,Can you tell me how to do this ? `cleanse it after you've fetched it `

Comment: @Sampath well, if you're going to do a `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` in the database, you'll have to do a basic string `REPLACE`; but yes: it is very awkward once it is in the database. My advice would be a: stop inserting bad data; then b: clean up the damaged data

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes,Good idea.Don't you like to put it as an answer ?

Comment: @Sampath I think the existing answer already covers that pretty much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As is evident of your latest screenshot the difference is this:

- The row with "number" 17 ends with the letter 'n': 6E00 = [0x006E](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/006E/index.htm)
- The row with "number" 18 after that `n` ends with two spaces: `20002000` = 2x [0x0020](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0020/index.htm)
- The row with "number" 19 after that `n` ends with a CR+LF linebreak sequence: `0D000A00` = [0x000D](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000D/index.htm) + [0x000A](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000A/index.htm)

So the three names really *are* different, it's just not a *visual* difference in the query tool that displays your rows.

To fix this during import you would have to trim whitespace from the end of the string, this should take care of those 3 different characters. Note that `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` only removes "blanks" which further down in the documentation suggests that only spaces are considered. You would thus have to use a different trim function, like in the programming language you're using, to do this trimming.

Comment: OK,I have done this.But still the same result no ? Why ? `select DISTINCT ltrim(rtrim(a.Company)) from [Legacy].[dbo].[Attorney] as a`

Comment: Yes, `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` only trims spaces, you will need to do this in a different tool, or use REPLACE (which may replace *inside* as well).

Comment: I have learnt a lot today from you and from `@Marc Gravell`. Thanks a lot :)